# Compile code based on your library support

Tags: c++, makefile, build, gpu

A portion of my C++ code is based on GPUs, so my one of my collegues that works on my same project doesn't have the possibility to compile it.

For example, in one file there is this line:

```
#include "opencv2/xfeatures2d/cuda.hpp"
```

Or in another file there is this line of code:

```
    cv::cuda::GpuMat imgGpu, descriptorsGpu, keypoints;
    imgGpu.upload(img);
```

Which are possible to compile only with CUDA (and GPUs) support.

How can we solve this? My only solution was to introduce a macro for every source file containing this code, wrap the section with macro and edit its value if you have the library supports, but this is a kind of nightmare.

Any better solution?

PS: our project is makefile-based

Comment: @drescherjm thanks!

Comment: It doesn't make any sense at all to make fifty bucks of hardware a team obstacle and hours upon hours of extra work.  Talk to your supervisor.

Comment: @HansPassant GPUs and in particular CUDA is not supported by everybody, in our team as for future users. This  is not a mandatory part of our project, it's an additional feature, and we should give the possibliity to work with both of them.

Answer (score 1):

A preferred approach is to isolate all GPU dependent code into a separate library. It may be worth it to build a mock or dummy substitute library that exposes same API but does not require CUDA. This separation of responsibilities may prove invaluable if one day you need to substitute CUDA for Vulcan or some other framework.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I don't think that what you are saying is possible (or more probably, I'm not understanding your approach): this optional part with the CUDA code is contained also in the system configuration code (if you have cuda, you can configure the system to take advantage of it). Are you telling me to create two versions of the entire project, one containing the CUDA code and the other one without it? I'm sorry if I don't understand your answer, maybe giving an example could help me.